# Order by using a subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to create message thread system. I have been able to do so. But the problem is the sorting in each particular thread. The query thatI have till now is:

```
SELECT
    freak_member_profiles.vchPicture,
    freak_membership_users.username,
    freak_membership_users.vchFullName,
    freak_message_center.vchMessage,
    freak_message_center.intMessageCenterID,
    intReceiverID,
    intSenderID,
    freak_message_center.enumStatus,
    date_format( freak_message_center.DATE, '%d %M' ) AS dates
FROM
    freak_message_center
    JOIN freak_membership_users ON freak_message_center.intSenderID = freak_membership_users.id
    JOIN freak_member_profiles  ON freak_message_center.intSenderID = freak_member_profiles.intMemberID
WHERE
    intReceiverID = '24'
GROUP BY
    intSenderID
ORDER BY
    freak_message_center.Date DESC
```

So how could I acheive ordering in each particular group?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the structure of your tables? What is the sample data, and the desired output you want?

Comment: Actually I getting the oldest entry from each group rather than the newest enteries. How this can be achieved using a subquery

Comment: `ORDER BY intSenderId, freak_message_center.Date DESC`?

Comment: @sahilagarwal put your schema here and expected output also here.http://www.sqlfiddle.com